# I have enabled the Activate Multiple Currencies by mistakenly

Tags: apex

As I go through the all the document After enabled, multiple currencies can’t be disabled for your organization. Please help me with how I can deactivate or resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned, you cannot disable this feature for your org now, however, you can still use the only one currency, that you have been using till now in your org. Just make sure it is enabled as main/default currency.

Comment: I have enabled it in development org. Is there any chance I can revert back by raising a support case to salesforce?

Comment: @SowmyaGS - refresh the sandbox from prod

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can not disable multiple currency once it is enabled.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_enable_multicurrency_implications.htm&type=5

If you have enabled this feature in sandbox then you can refresh the sandbox from production or from a different sandbox where multi currency is not enabled.

If you enabled the feature in production then raise a case with salesforce and may be salesforce support team can help by disabling the feature.